# Shutdown a PC on LAN from another PC using a batch file in Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, shutdown, lan

I'm just interested in knowing: can we shutdown a PC from another PC using a batch file if both are on the same LAN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `/m` switch for `shutdown` like this

```
shutdown /s /m \\computer1 /t 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the [shutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503%28v=ws.10%29) command from a batch running as a user with the correct permissions or use [psshutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx).

Comment: shutdown -s -t 2 is the code that shut down my pc. i want to shutdown another pc from my PC.

Comment: `/m \\<ComputerName>` : Specifies the target computer

Comment: shutdown -s /m \\ amith-016 -t 2    i use this code but it is not working

Comment: Well you cant just randomly shut down a computer on the network.. that would cause problems. You need to run the command under a user with the correct permissions - e.g. an admin on the target pc or pass the credentials to psshutdown

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
set computertoshutdown=COMPUTERNAME
set timetoshutdown =TIMEtoSHUTDOWN
set message=MESSAGE

shutdown -s -m \\%computertoshutdown% -t %timetoshutdown% -c "%message%"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work but you can shutdown any computer in your wifi range to find the name of the computer press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> keys all at the same time then go to computer name.

```
@Echo off
 cd\
 Echo Saman=Program
 REM ****************************
 REM * Program Variables *
 REM ****************************

 set varcomputer=[computername]
 goto loop
 :[computername]

 Exit

 REM ****************************
 REM * Program *
 REM ****************************

 :loop
 echo Shutting down %varcomputer%.
 shutdown -s -m \\%varcomputer% -t 600 -c "The computer is shutting down. Please save your work."
 goto %varcomputer
```